# Accessing filtered item list in a vuetify table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am building my first app in Vue and am also using Vuetify. In the app I have a Vuetify v-data-table which can be subjected to a myriad of filters. Now in another part of the app I need to access the currently filtered items from said table. I managed to do so by setting up a ref="table" on the table and by then utilizing the following code in my computed methods:

```
activeItems() {
  return this.$refs.table._data.internalCurrentItems
}
```

This works, but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to solve this. Is there a better, easier way to access this data?

Comment: You should have a look into State Management.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Comment: You have common ways two ways to communicate between components: 1. using [Event bus](https://medium.com/@andrejsabrickis/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860) method 2. using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) which is an application state manager if you want to know the difference between them you can check: - [https://medium.com/@kouty79/a-journey-from-the-eventbus-pattern-to-vuex-architecture-e06152df143f](https://medium.com/@kouty79/a-journey-from-the-eventbus-pattern-to-vuex-architecture-e06152df143f) - [https://